# Meaning and relevance for JRuby Gem message: "deprecated. use instead jars/installer"

Tags: java, jar, rubygems, jruby

I've been doing some searching on this.  The only close example was an old issue on GitHub for [Addressable](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable/pull/180) which it turns out was/is unrelated.

Looking a the output below I had the deprecated message:

```
 jruby -S gem install middleman-blog
 Fetching: addressable-2.3.7.gem (100%)
 deprecated. use instead jars/installer
 Successfully installed addressable-2.3.7
 Fetching: middleman-blog-3.5.3.gem (100%)
 Successfully installed middleman-blog-3.5.3
 2 gems installed
```

The question that come to mine include:

- What is deprecated?
- Which gem does the message relate to?
- Where can/would one look to figure out the action to take?

Finally, what is the significance or affect of the message on the gem-base and what does the phrase: "***use instead jars/installer***" mean!?  I found no similar examples in this scan:

- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jruby+jars%2Finstaller

Ideas welcome.  If nothing else I imagine the conversation will be educational about (some) that aspect of JRuby.  Oh details: JRuby 9.0, Java 8 u25 (u40 isn't working with JRuby), Windows 7.  *Many thanks* ...

Answer (score -1):

next time please answer your questions esp. if you [received response](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/2726)

... caused by jar-dependencies gem but it's [fixed](https://github.com/mkristian/jar-dependencies/commit/05b23457f298826abd61302a9127e4cc5278d4f0) since version **0.1.8**

Comment: The meaning was not explained.  Just that it is a mistake.